# jquery not sending button choice to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a search function that will accept a search string and send it to a php file for parsing a database column. I'd also like users to choose which aspect of the website they'd like to search (comics, artwork, or both). Comic and Artwork or stored in two separate tables.

This is a function that will accept an input search string from the html below and send it to a php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function search(searchString) {     
            //var site = $("#site").val();
            $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_input : searchString},
                function(returned_data) {
                    $("#output").html(returned_data);
                }
            );
        }
```

And this is javascript to accept a choice to search "comics", "artwork" or "all".

```
        function searchChoice(choice) {     
            alert("Choice: " + choice);
            $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_choice : choice}
           );
        }

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <!--Search filtering for comics, artwork, or both-->
<span class="search"><b>Search for: </b> </span>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<span class="search">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="comics" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">Comics</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="artwork" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">Artwork</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="all" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">All</button> 
</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<!--Search functionality-->
<span class="search">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)" name="input" value="" />
</span>

<br />
<span id="output"><span class="sidebarimages">  </span></span>
```

**PHP excerpt:**

```
$input = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0); 
$siteChoice = (isset($_GET['_choice']) ? ($_GET['_choice']) : "all");
```

You can see the javascript correctly alerting out "Choice: comics" when comics button is selected, but the php side, `echo "</br>Choice: " . $siteChoice;`, is echo'ing out "all", which is incorrect.

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned @E_p, that is the problem ... another option is to create a variable and store the data there ... try this:   you don't need change the html

```
   var mySearchString = 0;
   var myChoice = 'all';


function search(searchString) {     
        mySearchString = searchString;
        GetSearch();
        }

function searchChoice(choice) {     
            myChoice = choice;
            GetSearch();
            }

function GetSearch(){

 $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_input : mySearchString, _choice : myChoice},
        function(returned_data) {
            $("#output").html(returned_data);
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: I changed it- still didn't work. Can you explain why I need to change the PHP code like that? Thanks!

Comment: The change in the php is because you are sending an object "json" and the best approach would work it as such. That's what does not work? If you do a dump of the variables in php and _choice _input that have value?

Comment: @Growler what is the connection between the first function and the second because it works only that you didn't add the function to output the returned result

Comment: @codingbiz The connection is I'd like to give users the choice to search either all comics, all artwork, or both. So the choice buttons will send a parameter to the search.php file which will change which table is queried. And the first function is obviously just used to accept the search input and send it to that same search.php file for parsing.

Comment: see my updated answer - form.Serialize() using just one function instead of two

Comment: @codingbiz, I had not understood that running searchChoice should also do the search. Thx. Updated

Comment: @Mate wow this works perfectly! Can you explain your changes? What was wrong with the way I was trying it?!

Comment: Great! I understand you were trying to make 2 calls to your php, in the 1st by setting your "_choice" and in the 2nd running the search. You can not do this, since each call to the server is independent of the other. The change is that now you're sending both data in the same call, and the call are doing it for both events: at the click of a button and text entry.

Comment: @Mate Yeah I tried something similar before (Taking in both parameters) but it wasn't working at all. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You do not keep state for _choice.

When search is called it does not pass it to a server.

You need to change buttons to option and in search function pass both. to a server at the same time

Comment: What do you mean "change buttons to option"?

Comment: instead of <button> use <option>

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp (Radio Buttons) or http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: Ah yes, you have your button telling PHP one thing then your input field telling it another - the two are never connected. I guess you want to keep the buttons though because they look nicer than a <select> drop down in this instance. I'll write this one out in jsfiddle...

Comment: @popnoodles yes I originally had it in Radio button form but I thought these buttons looked nicer.

Comment: Than use something like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons if you want them to look like buttons

Comment: Edit: You don't need my jsfiddle. The answer submitted in the meantime by Mate is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the buttons with radio buttons and use form.Serialize()

```
<form id="searchform">
    <input type="radio" name="_choice" value="comics" />Comics<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="_choice" value="artwork" />Artwork<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="_choice" value="all" />All<br/>


    <input type="text" onkeyup="search()" name="_input" value="" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
  function search() {     
        //var site = $("#site").val();
        $.get("./scripts/search.php", $('#searchform').serialize(),
            function(returned_data) {
                $("#output").html(returned_data);
            }
        );
    }
```

The `.serialize()` function converts form input to JSON so you don't have to type manually, No more parameter, and no two functions, just one to do them all

Comment: you need to check `isset` if it evaluates to true. I suspect the $_GET were not populated. `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: My contribution is: you should not be sending the value to the function search(). This has no parameters :)